# Access Two Controllers in same bean - Dispatcher Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, spring-mvc

I am new to spring framework and hibernate. I want to Access Two Controllers in same view. Here is my Dispatcher Servlet code.

```
<bean name="/EditTask.htm"
      class="HumanResource.FindTaskController"
      p:HResourceService-ref="hresourceService" />

<bean name="/EditTask.htm"
      class="HumanResource.UpdateTaskController"
      p:HResourceService-ref="hresourceService" />
```

I have `EditTask.jsp` view. I want to access `FindTaskController` when user hits first submit and access `UpdateTaskController` when user hits second submit button in the same jsp.

I can't map Dispatcher Servlet as above because it genarates an exception `Bean name '/EditTask.htm' is already used in this file.`

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two `<form>`s in your jsp - one with `action="/findTask"` and the other with `action="/updateTask`. (assuming you map your two controllers / controller methods to these urls).